# Error when uploading file to Azure

Tags: azure

When I attempt to upload a file to Azure using

```
azure storage file upload foo.txt testshare testdir
```

I get

```
Error: If encoding is specified then the first argument must be a string
    at new Buffer (buffer.js:106:13)
    at Object.StorageUtil.getSpeedPrinter (/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/0.10.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/util/storage.util._js:594:21)
    at __$uploadFile (/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/0.10.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/commands/storage/storage.file._js:1040:45)
    at __$uploadFile (/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/0.10.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/commands/storage/storage.file._js:1031:25)
    at __$uploadFile (/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/0.10.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/commands/storage/storage.file._js:1034:23)
    at __tryCatch (/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/0.10.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/streamline/lib/callbacks/runtime.js:150:4)
    at ___ (/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/0.10.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/commands/storage/storage.file._js:1010:19)
    at ___ (/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/0.10.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/commands/storage/storage.file._js:1002:27)
    at __tryCatch (/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/0.10.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/streamline/lib/callbacks/runtime.js:150:4)
    at ___ (/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/0.10.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/commands/storage/storage.file._js:1000:23)
```

Comment: I just tried executing the above command and I did not encounter the error. FWIW, I downloaded the latest version of CLI tools and ran this on a Windows 10 PC. Can you tell what OS are you using (from your other question, it looks like you're using Mac) and the version of CLI tools?

Comment: @GauravMantri: `azure -version` gives `0.10.0 (node: 6.1.0)`. Mac OS X 10.11.4.

Answer (score 1):

As that error is the [reported and should be in the repo by 05/04](https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli/issues/2825), you may try to reinstall it for the 4.3.3 or try to go for the devbranch as described on the link above if you still see the error.

Comment: I'll wait for that to make it into release and try again then.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius personally, i would recommend to use the previous version - it looks like it provides the functionality, and works stable. But it is your choice indeed :)